# Get pdf from Firebase Storage

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Let's say I have a PDF file with 10 pages in Firebase Storage.
In the Firebase Storage references it has the code below.

```
let islandRef = storageRef.child("images/island.jpg")

// Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
islandRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
  if let error = error {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {
    // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
  }
}
```

I have tried this and did my best to download and also show the pdf file using PDFKit. But I always get an error from Firebase or something wrong in the console.

The way I did it was change the file name to the correct one and also change the number "1" to "10"

I don't know how to use the local files like in the reference.

//edited

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://---.appspot.com")
        let dataRef = storageRef.child("Slide.pdf")

        let downloadTask = dataRef.getData(maxSize: 100 * 2000 * 2000) { data, error in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Uh-oh, an error occurred!")
        } else {
            print("download success!!")

            let pdf:PDFDocument = PDFDocument(data: data!)!
            self.userDefaults.setValue(pdf, forKey: "PDF-Slide")
        }
    }
```

EDIT

Sorry for asking such a crazy question.
I got it fixed, I had the pdf file downloaded all along, and I was trying to save a pdf file to userdefault so the app always crashed since it doesn't support saving pdfdocuments

Comment: "Something wrong in the console". Sometimes we need to know errors to solve our problems. Please share your errors.

Comment: "I have tried this and did my best to download" Do you have the image in that path of the storage? "also show the pdf file using PDFKit" include the code of the attempt.

Comment: I added the code that I actually used

Comment: Sorry for asking a very easy question that sounded really hard.
But thank you for trying to help with my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userEmail = user.getEmail();
StorageReference str = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(userEmail+".pdf");
Toast.makeText(this, "pdf"+str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```